# How to enforce use of "std::" namespace in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, g++4.8

When using "g++" to compile some code, I can, for example, use types like "int32_t" (instead of "std::int32_t") or functions like "memcpy(...)" (instead of "std::memcpy(...)").

Is there a way to have the use of the namespace (or a "using namespace" statement) **enforced** by the compiler?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: I'm not sure but you do not want to do this.  Importing in all of `std` when you can use a couple `using std::whatever;` is not the way to go.  Also see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I believe he wants to *prevent* gcc from putting the names in the global namespace. So pretty much the opposite of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you misunderstood my question. I do **not** want to have the entire "std::" namespace available but I have it (even if I do not specify any "using" statement). The compiler is a lot more sloppy than I'd like to have it.

Comment: The standard leaves it "unspecified" whether an inclusion of `<cfoo>` also puts the names from `<foo.h>` in the global namespace...

Comment: @juanchopanza He wants `int32_t i = 5;` to be a compiler error unless `using namespace std;` was used beforehand.

Comment: @juanchopanza I want the compiler to require me to use the fully qualified name unless I "import" something from that namespace with a "using" statement.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Exactly. Or at least a warning. An error would actually be appropriate though, in my opinion.

Comment: @no.human.being OK, then unfortunately you can't, at least when if comes to names with equivalents in C header files (see Kerrek SB's comment.) It is annoying, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @juanchopanza I understand. Thanks!

Comment: [Also relevant](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6257).